# CSS Grid Layout - columns don't span

Tags: html, css, grid, multiple-columns

I have a grid layout with 7 items. What I'm trying to achieve is, that 1st row item takes all width (spans 3 columns), but 2nd and 3rd has 3 items/columns in each row.

So far I've tried every grid-column solution I could find, but nothing seems to be working so I believe it has to do something with the contents of grid items, but I can't see what's the problem.

Here is my code:

```css
.menu-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.menu-grid-container span {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.menu-grid-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-grid-container">
  <div class="menu-block item-1">
    <h2 class="menu-title">Promos</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-block item-2">
    <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
    <span class="menu-item">6 Alitas</span>
    <span class="price">9.99€</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-block item-3">
    <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
    <span class="menu-item">Menu Familiar</span>
    <span class="price">9.99€</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-block item-4">
    <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
    <span class="menu-item">Menu 2</span>
    <span class="price">9.99€</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-block item-5">
    <h2 class="menu-title">Menus</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-block item-6">
    <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
    <span class="menu-item">Menu 1</span>
    <span class="price">9.99€</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-block item-7">
    <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
    <span class="menu-item">Menu 2</span>
    <span class="price">9.99€</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CodePen

https://codepen.io/WhatIsThisPS/pen/GRgEqRE

Comment: Have you tried using tables? The `colspan` attribute for `<td>` could help.

Comment: I need it to be responsive, that's why I went with grid

Comment: You have a typo in `.item1` should be `.item-1`, Also `repeat(3, 1fr)` this will generate 3 columns and 4 lines so `grid-column: 1 / 3;` should be `grid-column: 1 / 4;` or  `grid-column: 1 / span 3;` If you only specify numbers that means the lines if you want columns you add `span` keyword. More on [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)

Comment: I knew it had to be something trivial like that. Simple typo. Thanks for clarification on 1 / 4 and 1 / span 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.menu-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 1rem 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.menu-grid-container span {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.menu-grid-container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.item1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-grid-container">

        <div class="menu-block item-1 item1">
             <h2 class="menu-title">Promos</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-block item-2">
             <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
             <span class="menu-item">6 Alitas</span>
          <span class="price">9.99€</span>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-block item-3">
             <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
             <span class="menu-item">Menu Familiar</span>
             <span class="price">9.99€</span>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-block item-4">
             <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
             <span class="menu-item">Menu 2</span>
             <span class="price">9.99€</span>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-block item-5">
             <h2 class="menu-title">Menus</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-block item-6">
             <img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="" class="menu-img">
             <span class="menu-item">Menu 1</span>
             <span class="price">9.99€</span>
        </div>
        
 </div>
```